# How to avoid typing leading zeros?

Tags: sapui5

I have an input that supports suggestion

[image]

To search for a number, I have to type leading zeros first. How can I bypass it?

The code:

```
<Label text="Assign to" labelFor="pmRespPers"/>
<Input id="pmRespPers" type="Text" placeholder="Enter Person respons." showSuggestion="true"
    suggestionRows="{EAMMALFUNCTION>/I_PMContactCardEmployee}">
    <layoutData>
        <layout:GridData span="L7 M7 S12"/>
    </layoutData>
    <suggestionColumns>
        <Column hAlign="Begin" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
            <Label text="Number"/>
        </Column>
        <Column hAlign="Center" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
            <Label text="Fullname"/>
        </Column>
    </suggestionColumns>
    <suggestionRows>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Label text="{EAMMALFUNCTION>PersonnelNumber}"/>
                <Label text="{EAMMALFUNCTION>EmployeeFullName}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </suggestionRows>
</Input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution:

```
    onSuggest: function(oEvent) {
        const oSuggestionRows = oEvent.getSource().getSuggestionRows();
        oSuggestionRows.map(a => {
            const oFirstLabel = a.getCells()[0];
            const iPersonnel = oFirstLabel.getText();
            const iPlConverted = parseInt(iPersonnel, 10);
            oFirstLabel.setText(iPlConverted);
            return oFirstLabel;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ["suggest" event](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/events/suggest) in the Input. It will be fire each time the user types in the Input.

As parameters of the event object, you get the "value".
So in the event handler function modify the value as you want (adding the zeros) and filter the list of suggestions with the modified value.

You need to disable the default filtering as well to avoid confilcts. Here the snippet: https://jsbin.com/welimufado/edit?html,output

```
<Input id="productInput" type="Text" placeholder="Enter Product ..."
  showSuggestion="true" filterSuggests="false" suggestionItems="{/products}" suggest="onSuggest">
  <suggestionItems>
     <core:Item text="{Name}" />
  </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

And the event handler

```
onSuggest: function(oEvent){
    var sValue = oEvent.getParameters().suggestValue;
    var sModifiedValue = "0000" + sValue;
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sModifiedValue);
    oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(oFilter);
}
```

Snippet with tabular suggestion:
https://jsbin.com/wovovofece/edit?html,output

Comment: With `oEvent.getParameters().suggestionColumns`, I've got `undefined`. Why?

Comment: sorry, I think I misunderstood the API. I think "suggestionColumns" is only defined when configuring tabular suggestions. Check my updates in the answer.

Comment: So it is not possible to use it with `suggestionRows`?

Comment: Sure, of course you can... just change the binding you get from the input object like this `oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionRows").filter(oFilter);`

I wrote another snippet showing it. last line in my answer